# About the exponential sequence

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry, hodge-theory, complex-manifolds

For a complex analytic space $X$, we have the exponential sequence

$$0\to\mathbf{Z}(1)_X\to\mathcal{O}_X\to\mathcal{O}_X^{\times}\to 1$$
the last map being the exponential $\text{exp}$.

For $d>0$ integer, the constant sheaf $\mathbf{Z}(d)_X$ is, by definition, $\mathbf{Z}(1)^{\otimes d}_X$. Explicitly, $\mathbf{Z}(d)_X$ is the constant sheaf with value $\mathbf{Z}\cdot(2\pi i)^d\subset\mathbf{C}$.

Does $\mathbf{Z}(d)_X$ fit into a new exponential sequence, perhaps modifying $\text{exp}$?

Pushing out the exponential sequence at the beginning, along the quotient map $\mathbf{Z}(1)_X\to \mu_{n, X}$ (where $\mu_n$) is the sheaf on $n$th roots of unity on $X$) we get the exponential sequence

$$1\to \mu_{n,X}\to\mathcal{O}_X^{\times}\xrightarrow{x^n} \mathcal{O}_X^{\times}\to 1$$

where $\text{exp} : \mathbf{C}\to\mathbf{C}^{\times}$ induces a $\mathbf{Z}$-module isomorphism $\mathbf{Z}\cdot (2\pi i)/n \simeq \mu_n$.

Taking inverse limits along the $n$th power maps one gets the sequence

$$1\to \widehat{\mathbf{Z}}(1)_X\to\lim \mathcal{O}_X^{\times}\to \mathcal{O}_X^{\times}\to 1$$

If $\mathbf{Z}(d)_X$ fits into an exponential sequence as asked before, then the pushout of such sequence along the profinite completion map should give a sequence whose left term is $\widehat{\mathbf{Z}}(d)_X$, and the $n$th power maps should be turned into... what? ($n/d$-th power maps?)

I'm sorry if this is too elementary. I'm finding my way to think about it.

Comment: While I understand the spirit of your first question, a literal and uninteresting answer is yes:  $\mathbf{Z}(d)$ is kernel $\exp((2\pi i)^{1-d}-)$. Perhaps, more interesting is to realize it as quasi-isomorphic to the $d$-fold tensor product of $\mathcal{O}_X\to \mathcal{O}_X^{\times}$.